# Return View() or PartialView()? How to decide?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I hava an Action:

```
public ActionResult GetOrders(int id)
{
  ...
}
```

When I access it through hyperlink(~/Order/GetOrders/1), I want GetOrder return `View()`, the whole page.

When through `@Html.Action("GetOrders")`, I want it return PartialView() to be a part of a page.

---

Now i settled the problem using Erik Philips's method.

```
public ActionResult GetOrders(int id)
{
    var orders = db.Order.Where(a => a.AdCompanyID == id).ToList();
    ViewBag.AdCompanyName = db.AdCompany.Where(a => a.ID == id).Select(a => a.Name).First().ToString();
    if (ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
    {
        ViewBag.isPartial = true;
        return PartialView(orders);
    }
    ViewBag.isPartial = false;
    return View(orders);
}
@{Html.RenderAction("GetOrders", new { id = Model.ID });}
@Html.ActionLink("Related orders", "GetOrders", new { id = item.ID })
```

in GetOrders.cshtml:

```
@if (ViewBag.isPartial == false)
{
    ...
}
```

to generate different view.

Queti M. Porta thanks all the same!

Comment: You are using MVC version 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ControllerContext.IsChildAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.ischildaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
  if (ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
  {
    return PartialView("GetOrdersPartial", model);
  }
  return View("GetOrders", model);
}
```

Also, I would recommend using [`Html.RenderAction`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

*Updated per Comment*

I'd also mention that I've never had the need to do this, in my own experience.  Either you really have a completely different view, or you are unaware that PartialView will return a view without a Layout.

Comment: it works, just what i want! thx!!! But i return PartialView("GetOrdersPartial"), so i have two views GetOrders.cshtml & GetOrdersPartial.cshtml how to combine them?

Comment: Updated per your comment.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to pass in a parameter into the action method to let it know how you want  the view rendered.

```
public ActionResult GetOrders(int id, bool? isPartial)
{
  return (isPartial.HasValue() && isPartial.Value)
         ? PartialView()
         : View();
}
```

In the above example, we are passing in the `isPartial`, however, you can also check to see if the request was done via ajax using `Request.IsAjaxRequest`

Other than that, there aren't many other ways to determine the method of the request.

Comment: @Html.Action("GetContacts", new { id = Model.ID })
@Html.ActionLink("Related orders", "GetOrders", new { id = item.ID })
Is there any differences I can detect from the object 'Request' to distinguish the two method above?

Comment: Action renders a method as html, ActionLink renders an html anchor.